# Where to find a list of U.S. policy changes for causal studies?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, causality

I'm currently trying to figure how the topic of my paper, which is supposed to be related to policy evaluation (causal inference). I thought it would be great if I could first obtain a list of recent U.S. policy changes, and then decide what exact policy I would like to dive in. 
If you are familiar with this field, would you please recommend to me some sources / lists for U.S. policy changes?

Comment: Depending on the type of policies you are looking for, this question may be a better fit for [politics.se].

Comment: I don’t know of any simple list but following news is good way how to get some ideas. BBC, WSJ, The Economist, Forbes, any journal that focuses on economic issues would be good sources, you can peruse through old issues of WSJ for example or watch on YouTube the last year BBC financial economics news it should give you plenty interesting topics to choose from